# Use keyless entity on "many" side in one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I'm using **Entity Framework Core 5.0** for **SQLite** and have such schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Elem (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    title TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Property (
    elemId INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    value FLOAT NOT NULL
);
```

I created the following classes:

```cs
[Table("Elem")]
public class dbElem {
    [Key]
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<Property> props { get; set; }
}
[Table("Property")]
public class dbProperty {
    public long elemId { get; set; }
    public virtual dbElem elem { get; set; }
    
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

In the `OnModelCreating` function, I wrote the following:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<dbProperty>(entity => {
    entity.HasNoKey();
    entity.HasOne(f => f.elem).WithMany(f => f.props).HasForeignKey(f => f.elemId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
});
```

Everything looks logical, but I get an error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The navigation '' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type 'dbProperty'. Navigations can only target entity types with keys.'`

**Is there any reason for this restriction?**

**Can I somehow influence the EFC to not add a key?**